# Replace values dataframe column values if there is a perceptual change regarding the previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation

I have the following dataframe where if the drop or raise regarding the previous row larger or equal than 50% is to be replaced with NaN. (i need that in order to interpolate outliers)

```
x=[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
y=[6,6,3,3,8,8,7,2,2,2]

data=pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

My output should be this

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 6 |
| 17 | 6 |
| 18 | NaN |
| 19 | NaN |
| 20 | 8 |
| 21 | 8 |
| 22 | 7 |
| 23 | NaN |
| 24 | NaN |
| 25 | NaN |

Comment: can you check the input? `y` has one element less than `x`, I assumed you forgot a value

Comment: i ve double checked the input and i haven't forgotten any value

Comment: you checked your initial input `y=[6,6,3,3,8,8,7,2,2]` or my update of your question `y=[6,6,3,3,8,8,7,2,2,2]`? ;)

Comment: ok i see it now. You have already update the question! :)

Comment: so did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Your input is incorrect, so I assumed the following:

```
    x  y
0  16  6
1  17  6
2  18  3
3  19  3
4  20  8
5  21  8
6  22  7
7  23  2
8  24  2
9  25  2
```

You can use `pct_change` to find the values where there is a drop, `mask` and  `ffill` to identify the plateaus, and generate a mask:

```
s = data['y'].pct_change()
data['y2'] = data['y'].mask(s.mask(s.eq(0)).ffill().le(-0.5))
```

output:

```
    x  y   y2
0  16  6  6.0
1  17  6  6.0
2  18  3  NaN
3  19  3  NaN
4  20  8  8.0
5  21  8  8.0
6  22  7  7.0
7  23  2  NaN
8  24  2  NaN
9  25  2  NaN
```